# PHP - Retornar valor da database - valor específico

Tags: php, html

preciso de uma luz para retornar somente um valor específico de acordo com o login efetuado.

Exemplo: se o username da database for "Amora" retornar o valor da coluna Nome cujo o username seja Amora.

Acredito que esteja relacionado ao SELECT mas não sei como fazer se puderem me dar alguma dica.

```
    <?php
require_once 'config.php';

try {
    

    $sql = 'SELECT username,
                    password,
                    Nome
               FROM login
              ORDER BY Nome';

    $q = $con->query($sql);
     $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   die("Could not connect to the database $database :" . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WMS - Lear Betim</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
              
                <tbody>
                    <?php while ($row = $q->fetch()): ?>
                        <tr>
                           <td> <?php echo htmlspecialchars('Olá' . ", " . $row['Nome']); ?></td> 
                        </tr>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Se for pra retornar o registro da tabela login onde Nome = Amora  select colunas from login where Nome = 'Amora' ....

Comment: Obrigado o seu comentário me ajudou a solucionar o problema em questão.              Usei  $sql = "SELECT username,
                    password,
                    Nome
               FROM login
              WHERE username = 'amora'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário incluir a cláusula WHERE no SQL de consulta ao banco de dados.

### A cláusula SQL WHERE

A cláusula `WHERE` é usada para filtrar registros. É usado para extrair apenas os registros que atendem a uma condição especificada. Fonte: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp).

Sintaxe WHERE:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```

Condititon pode ser, por exemplo: `WHERE Nome = 'Amora'`. Pode ter mais de uma condição, como: `WHERE username = 'Amora_Amora' AND password = '123456'`. Também é possível utilizar outros operadores lógicos e condicionais (exemplo [link1](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_operators.asp) e [link2](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)), entre eles: `=`, `<`, `>`, `<>`, `AND`, `OR`, `BETWEEN` e etc.

Nota: A cláusula `WHERE` não é utilizado somente em `SELECT`, ele também é usado em `UPDATE`, `DELETE` e etc.

---

No PHP, ao utilizar o PDO, é possível passar esse valor dinamicamente. É recomendável utilizar o `prepare` ([aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php)), isso ajuda a prevenir ataques de *SLQ Injection* em consultas que são disparadas a partir de parâmetros externos principalmente, por exemplo. Ficaria similar ao código:

```
$nomeUsuario = "Amora"; //aqui seria possível mudar para um conteúdo de GET/POST, por exemplo.
$sql = "SELECT username,
               password,
               Nome
        FROM login
        WHERE Nome = :nome";
$q = $con->prepare($sql);
$q->bindParam(":nome", $nomeUsuario);
$q->execute();
$consulta = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```